# Why are there no Makefiles for automation in Python projects?

Tags: python, automation, makefile, rake

As a long time Python programmer, I wonder, if a central aspect of Python culture eluded me a long time: What do we do instead of Makefiles?

Most ruby-projects I've seen (not just rails) use *Rake*, shortly after *node.js* became popular, there was *cake*. In many other (compiled and non-compiled) languages there are classic *Make* files.

But in Python, no one seems to need such infrastructure. I randomly picked Python projects on GitHub, and they had no automation, besides the installation, provided by `setup.py`.

**What's the reason behind this?**

Is there nothing to automate? Do most programmers prefer to run style checks, tests, etc. manually?

Some examples:

- `dependencies` sets up a virtualenv and installs the dependencies
- `check` calls the `pep8` and `pylint` commandlinetools.
- the `test` task depends on `dependencies` enables the virtualenv, starts selenium-server for the integration tests, and calls `nosetest`
- the `coffeescript` task compiles all coffeescripts to minified javascript
- the `runserver` task depends on `dependencies` and `coffeescript`
- the `deploy` task depends on `check` and `test` and deploys the project.
- the `docs` task calls sphinx with the appropiate arguments

Some of them are just one or two-liners, but IMHO, they add up. Due to the Makefile, I don't have to remember them.

To clarify: I'm not looking for a Python equivalent for Rake. I'm glad with paver. I'm looking for the reasons.

Comment: What would you automate in a Python project?

Comment: running the tests/checkers, creating debian packages (no setup.py-plugin i found worked for me right now), in web projects running the testserver, deployment, minifying css and js... i have no projects where there isnt at least one or two tasks that deserve automation

Comment: @kappla: You would **never** use `setup.py` for running tests, running a test server, minifying css and js.  None of that is even related to what `setup.py` does.  This is very confusing.  Can you **update** the question to list things you need to "automate"?  Can you read the distutils documentation to see what `setup.py` is **supposed** to do, and revise your question?

Comment: @S.Lott: i considered setup.py to automate packaging, installation and publication on pypi. That, and the fact that it would be theoretically possible to add my tasks as 'actions' is why i mentioned it. I revised the question.

Comment: @keppla: "add my tasks as 'actions"?  What other tasks are there?  I'm still unclear on what your use case is?  "Things i usually automate are" isn't terribly interesting because these are all one-line commands.  What's to "automate"?

Comment: @keppla.  Also.  What's a stylecheck?  Can you provide a definition or an example of this in Python?

Comment: @S.Lott: sorry, i though, stylecheck was a common term. I meant things like Pylint, Pyflakes and the pep8-cmdtool.

Comment: If you want makefiles just .. write them? What's stopping you?

Comment: @Jochen Ritzel: as said: i am already using them. i want to know why nobody else in the python community is using them. Maybe, there there is more 'pythonic' way i am not aware of?

Comment: @keppla: "nobody else".  Please.  Avoid hyperbole.  Claiming you're the only one using `make` makes your question sound very silly.

Comment: @S.Lott: sorry, i thought from the context it was clear it would be understood as 'only a few'.

Comment: @kappa: There is also Ant, your IDE's automation features, bash scripts and so on. I guess nobody felt the need to to reinvent the wheel yet.

Comment: So how did you eventually decide to automate those things? I currently looking for an idiomatic way to `install-run` the application (i.e. create `venv`, install `requirements.txt`, install the project itself and run it from the `venv`)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> Is there nothing to automate?

Not really.  All but two of the examples are one-line commands.

**tl;dr** Very little of this is really interesting or complex.  Very little of this seems to benefit from "automation".

Due to documentation, I don't have to remember the commands to do this.

> Do most programmers prefer to run stylechecks, tests, etc. manually?

Yes.

> generation documentation, 
>   the docs task calls sphinx with the appropiate arguments

It's one line of code.  Automation doesn't help much.
`sphinx-build -b html source build/html`.  That's a script.  Written in Python.

We do this rarely.  A few times a week.  After "significant" changes.

> running stylechecks (Pylint, Pyflakes and the pep8-cmdtool).
>   check calls the pep8 and pylint commandlinetools

We don't do this.  We use unit testing instead of pylint.
You could automate that three-step process.

**But I can see how SCons or make might help someone here.**

> tests

There might be space for "automation" here.   It's two lines: the non-Django unit tests (`python test/main.py`) and the Django tests.  (`manage.py test`).  Automation could be applied to run both lines.

We do this dozens of times each day.  We never knew we needed "automation".

> dependecies sets up a virtualenv and installs the dependencies

Done so rarely that a simple list of steps is all that we've ever needed.  We track our dependencies very, very carefully, so there are never any surprises.

We don't do this.

> the test task depends on dependencies enables the virtualenv, starts selenium-server for the integration tests, and calls nosetest

The `start server & run nosetest` as a two-step "automation" makes some sense.  It saves you from entering the two shell commands to run both steps.

> the coffeescript task compiles all coffeescripts to minified javascript

This is something that's very rare for us.  I suppose it's a good example of something to be automated.  Automating the  one-line script could be helpful.

**I can see how SCons or make might help someone here.**

> the runserver task depends on dependencies and coffeescript

Except.  The dependencies change so rarely, that this seems like overkill.  I supposed it can be a good idea of you're not tracking dependencies well in the first place.

> the deploy task depends on check and test and deploys the project.

It's an `svn co` and `python setup.py install` on the server, followed by a bunch of customer-specific copies from the subversion area to the customer `/www` area.  That's a script.  Written in Python.

It's not a general make or SCons kind of thing.  It has only one actor (a sysadmin) and one use case.  We wouldn't ever mingle deployment with other development, QA or test tasks.

Comment: so, i take, instead of having a single file for your automation (like Make, Rake, Paver), you prefer having multiple scripts?

Comment: @keppla:  Yes.  I run them when I need them.  I don't get what part of this I would "automate".  Can you provide some example of a sequence or a script of steps that would require "automation"?  I do these one at a time, never two steps together.  Never.  I don't see what "automation" you're talking about.  Can you provide a sample script or sequence of steps that you think of as requiring "automation".

Comment: I dont see how pythonev has something to do with not tracking dependencies. I use it to not spam my development system, and because different projects may have different requirements, that sometimes conflict.

Comment: @keepla: "not spam my development system"?  "different projects may have different requirements"?  While all true, we don't seem to be building environments often enough to justify "automation".  They mostly just sit there, already fully built.  It's not clear why you're rebuilding them so often that automation is helping you.

Answer (score 20):

Actually, automation is useful to Python developers too!

Invoke is probably the closest tool to what you have in mind, for automation of common repetitive Python tasks: https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke

With invoke, you can create a tasks.py like this one (borrowed from the invoke docs)

```
from invoke import run, task

@task
def clean(docs=False, bytecode=False, extra=''):
    patterns = ['build']
    if docs:
        patterns.append('docs/_build')
    if bytecode:
        patterns.append('**/*.pyc')
    if extra:
        patterns.append(extra)
    for pattern in patterns:
        run("rm -rf %s" % pattern)

@task
def build(docs=False):
    run("python setup.py build")
    if docs:
        run("sphinx-build docs docs/_build")
```

You can then run the tasks at the command line, for example:

```
$ invoke clean
$ invoke build --docs
```

Another option is to simply use a Makefile. For example, a Python project's Makefile could look like this:

```
docs:
    $(MAKE) -C docs clean
    $(MAKE) -C docs html
    open docs/_build/html/index.html

release: clean
    python setup.py sdist upload

sdist: clean
    python setup.py sdist
    ls -l dist
```

Comment: The question is why don't they, not "provide me with rhetoric to convince project maintainers that they should".

Comment: Your `Makefile` has only phony targets (without declaring them `.PHONY`, which means that `make` will actually look for the existence of files called `release`, `docs` or `sdist`). Your `Makefile` is just acting as a repository for scripted actions; it's not performing an incremental rebuild of a compiled code base (what `make` is designed for).   None of it is going to make sense to the average Python programmer who doesn't know anything about `make`.

Comment: Is it really a common way to use `Makefile` to automate things in python?

Answer (score 12):

[`Setuptools`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can automate a lot of things, and for things that aren't built-in, it's easily extensible.

- To run unittests, you can use the `setup.py test` command after having added a `test_suite` argument to the `setup()` call. ([documentation](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#test-build-package-and-run-a-unittest-suite))
- Dependencies  (even if not available on PyPI) can be handled by adding a `install_requires`/`extras_require`/`dependency_links` argument to the `setup()` call. ([documentation](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies))
- To create a `.deb` package, you can use the [`stdeb`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/stdeb#sdist-dsc-distutils-command) module.
- For everything else, you can [add custom setup.py commands](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#extending-and-reusing-setuptools).

But I agree with `S.Lott`, most of the tasks you'd wish to automate (except dependencies handling maybe, it's the only one I find really useful) are tasks you don't run everyday, so there wouldn't be any real productivity improvement by automating them.

Answer (score 6):

There is a number of options for automation in Python. I don't think there is a culture against automation, there is just not one dominant way of doing it. The common denominator is [distutils](http://docs.python.org/distutils/).

The one which is closed to your description is [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/). This is mostly used in the Zope/Plone world.

I myself use a combination of the following: [Distribute](http://packages.python.org/distribute/), [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/) and [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/). I am mostly developing using Django that has manage.py for automation commands.

It is also being actively worked on in [Python 3.3](http://docs.python.org/dev/packaging/)

Comment: i didnt want to imply a culture against automation. 'Is there nothing to automate?' was meant as 'is everything already automated and i dont get that', not as 'am i the only smart guy who automates'?

Answer (score 2):

Any decent test tool has a way of running the entire suite in a single command, and nothing is stopping you from using rake, make, or anything else, really.

There is little reason to invent a new way of doing things when existing methods work perfectly well - why re-invent something just because YOU didn't invent it? (NIH).

Comment: i know that nothing stops me, as said in the question, i am currently using paver. i am interested why only a few pythonistas see the need for a make, while in other communities many seem to see it.

Comment: Those that do, use make. Or whatever other tool they feel they need.

Answer (score 2):

The `make` utility is an optimization tool which reduces the time spent building a software image. The reduction in time is obtained when all of the intermediate materials from a previous build are still available, and only a small change has been made to the inputs (such as source code). In this situation, `make` is able to perform an "incremental build": rebuild only a subset of the intermediate pieces that are impacted by the change to the inputs.

When a complete build takes place, all that `make` effectively does is to execute a set of scripting steps. These same steps could just be deposited into a flat script. The `-n` option of `make` will in fact print these steps, which makes this possible.

A Makefile isn't "automation"; it's "automation with a view toward optimized incremental rebuilds."  Anything scripted with any scripting tool is automation.

So, why would Python project eschew tools like `make`? Probably because Python projects don't struggle with long build times that they are eager to optimize. And, also, the compilation of a `.py` to a `.pyc` file does not have the same web of dependencies like a `.c` to a `.o`.

A C source file can `#include` hundreds of dependent files; a one-character change in any one of these files can mean that the source file must be recompiled. A properly written `Makefile` will detect when that is or is not the case.

A big C or C++ project without an incremental build system would mean that a developer has to wait *hours* for an executable image to pop out for testing. Fast, incremental builds are essential.

In the case of Python, probably all you have to worry about is when a `.py` file is newer than its corresponding `.pyc`, which can be handled by simple scripting: loop over all the files, and recompile anything newer than its byte code. Moreover, compilation is optional in the first place!

So the reason Python projects tend not to use `make` is that their need to perform incremental rebuild optimization is low, and they use other tools for automation; tools that are more familiar to Python programmers, like Python itself.

Answer (score 1):

The original PEP where this was raised can be found [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0229/). Distutils has become the standard method for distributing and installing Python modules.

Why? It just happens that python is a wonderful language to perform the installation of Python modules with.

Comment: but installation isn't the only thing i want to automate, see my comment above.

Comment: Ahh, in this case I don't have an answer for you; it is beyond my field of knowledge. Hope someone can provide some good rationale.

Answer (score 0):

Here are few examples of makefile usage with python:

https://blog.horejsek.com/makefile-with-python/

https://krzysztofzuraw.com/blog/2016/makefiles-in-python-projects.html

I think that a most of people is not aware "makefile for python" case. It could be useful, but "sexiness ratio" is too small to propagate rapidly (just my PPOV).