# Installing into a venv with setup.py setuptools

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, setuptools, python-venv

I'm looking for a way to do a single-command installation of the whole python application into a `venv` by a specific path.

---

I did some research about this topic and particularly in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18420304/2786156) there was a discussion about `Makefile` automation of the process. It also suggests to use [pyinvoke](https://www.pyinvoke.org/), which appeared to me as a command line commands wrapped into python. So I currently wrote the following simple on-the-knee shell script:

`install_venv.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

PYTHON="$1"
VENV_PATH="$2"
SOURCE_ROOT="$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$BASH_SOURCE")")"

echo "$PYTHON"
echo "$VENV_PATH"
echo "$SOURCE_ROOT"

cd $SOURCE_ROOT
$PYTHON -m venv $VENV_PATH
source "$VENV_PATH/bin/activate"
python -m pip install -r "$SOURCE_ROOT/requirements.txt"
python setup.py install
```

This script can be run, say as `./install_venv.sh python3.7 /tmp/test_venv`. It does not handle the case if `venv` already exists by the path, but it can be extended in a straightforward way.

It looks like a very common task, so maybe `setuptools` already has a way to do so or writing such scripts is still necessary? Or what is the preferred way?

Comment: Check out the `pipx` tool https://github.com/pipxproject/pipx

Comment: @wim Can it run wheel packages by their paths? I installed `python3.7 -m pipx install target/dist/my_fancy_app-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl` and got the error `Could not find package target/dist/my_fancy_app-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl. Is the name correct?`. Running also did not work as I expected `python3.7 -m pipx run target/dist/my_fancy_app-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl` raises `'target/dist/my_fancy_app-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl' executable script not found in package 'target/dist/my_fancy_app-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl'. Available executable scripts:`. I examined the package and the scripts were there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what the true intention is...

---

Maybe one of these tools can help:

- https://pypi.org/project/zapp/
- https://pypi.org/project/shiv/
- https://pypi.org/project/pex/
- https://pypi.org/project/pipx/

These tools allow you to install a Python application with all their required dependencies in an isolated way. Some are based on virtual environments some are not.

---

Maybe you are looking for a tool such as [poetry](https://pypi.org/project/poetry/) (or [pipenv](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/) but not sure if it's still being maintained or not).

---

More simple and straightforward, there is this plugin for *setuptools*:

- https://pypi.org/project/venvtools/

Comment: I tried `pipx`, but it seems it cannot install a packge from a `.whl` archive. My primary intention is to automate `venv` setup, libraries `requirements.txt` installation and essentially install the application in it with just a single command.

Comment: Maybe [tox](https://pypi.org/project/tox/), this is good at creating virtual environments and installing _requirements.txt_ in them. It does a lot more though, so it might be too complicated. For the use case with the _wheel_ nothing comes to mind. I would probably script it myself if I were in your situation, you are on the right track with your shell script, or maybe do it directly with a Python script instead.

Comment: In the absence of instant solutions py-script probably a better choice... I think